# Expo / TouchableOpacity onPress() not responding

Tags: react-native, expo, touchableopacity

I'm trying to reproduce a pomodoro app from an online course.
I've been looking at my code for several hours, going back and forth with the course, but can't find my error.

TouchableOpacity or Pressable used in RoundedButton component doesn't trigger onPress()
I tried different command to test if my logic with setStarted was flawe, without success.

Anyone can help me find my bug ?

Here is the link to the expo : https://snack.expo.dev/@battlepoap/focus-time

RoundedButton.js:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

    export const RoundedButton = ({
      style = {},
      textStyle = {},
      size = 125,
      ...props
    }) => {
      return (
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity style={[styles(size).radius, style]}>
            <Text style={[styles(size).text, textStyle]}>{props.title}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    };

    const styles = (size) =>
      StyleSheet.create({...});
```

Example with Focus.js where we add a task by pressing on the RoundedButton :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';

import { RoundedButton } from '../../components/RoundedButton';
import { fontSizes, spacing } from '../../utils/sizes';

export const Focus = ({ addSubject }) => {
  const [tempSubject, setTempSubject] = useState(null);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>What do you want to focus on ?</Text>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={{ flex: 1, marginRight: spacing.sm }}
            onSubmitEditing={({ nativeEvent }) => {
              setTempSubject(nativeEvent.text);
            }}
          />
          <RoundedButton
            size={50}
            title="+"
            onPress={() => addSubject = tempSubject}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

*sic* In the additional files there was ....

> One thing we however need to add in order to make sure the button triggers is the `onPress` method. This method allows us to trigger the touch event of the user. Don't forget it!!

```
<TouchableOpacity style={[styles(size).radius, style]}> 
    <Text 
        style={[styles(size).text, textStyle]} 
        onPress={props.onPress}>
            {props.title}
    </Text> 
</TouchableOpacity>
```